# Gazebo Tutorials for creating a plugin?

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created some sensors and i want to make plugins of these sensor like the one defined in [gazebo_plugins page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo_plugins)

Are there any guidelines or tutorials for creating Gazbeo plugins?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10957/gazebo-tutorials-for-creating-a-plugin?/) by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2011-08-19

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-24**:
We have not been advertising much about plugin creation due to the fact that we are re-working a lot of the internal structures in gazebo on kforge.  What do you need the plugin to do?

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-20**:
I need to create the plugins from the files i have made. I didn't found any tutorials about making plugins for ros

**Comment by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on 2016-12-18**:
@hsu I have a question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/250181/simulation-and-actuation-of-custom-model-in-ros-gazebo/ and I need custom plugin to actuate joints. I have seen some; But, I am having a hard time understanding function calls. Thanks for time and consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For now, the best thing to do is to follow the [template provided in gazebo_plugins](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_template.cpp) or mimic any of the examples in [gazebo_plugins](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo_plugins).  Also take a look at [gazebo configuration page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/GazeboConfiguration) to see how to setup plugin paths in your own packages.

**Please keep in mind, plugin API's will change soon in F-Turtle, and will require some significant migratory changes/rewrites.**

Proceeding on with the current setup, if you take a look at the template presented, there are 4 relevant member functions,

- constructor - this is called once when the plugin is instantiated in `Model::Load(...)`
- InitChild() - this is called once during `Model::Init()`
- UpdateChild() - this is called once per `Model::Update()` call
- FiniChild() - this is called once when a Model / Body is deleted, or simulator is shutting down, before destruction happens
- destructor

The new plugin API for gazebo 1.0.0 RC to be released with Fuerte is described on the [new gazebo wiki](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/plugins).  Conversion from old plugin to the new format requires [rewrite work described here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/plugins/converting_old_plugins).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on 2012-01-08**:
@sak    hello sak,i would be interested in your sonarsensor plugin,Did you have success? how can i use your sonar plugin in gazebo? greets

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-25**:
Now i want to place all these in a package, so if someone wants , he/she can use it.

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-25**:
i have created IR and sonar sensors, using the above functions (following the GazeboRosLaser). now i want to release that files in the form of plugins ( there are a large number of files like sonar.gazebo.xacro, sonar.urdf.xacro, sonarsensor, changes done to gz.h and MultiRayShape.cc)